# Cannot open port on my router

Tags: windows

Am trying to forward my public facing IP port to the IP of my server with a D-Link router in between so that port 80 on the public IP forwards to port 80 on the server (not in DMZ). Do I need to put the server in a DMZ for this to work? Do I need to forward port 80 on both TCP and UDP or just TCP in order for my web-server (IIS) on my server to be accessible using the public IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am bit unsure to what you are asking.

You simply need to make sure that your ISP is giving you an unfiltered service (Some block key infrastructure ports - 25, 80 etc.)

If you are saying that you have a single router, simply make sure that you have a firewall set up for Port 80 or HTTP (same thing, some list as ports, others as applications) that points to the internal IP of the server hosting it.

If however you are saying you have two routers with a DMZ in between -  you could have a problem to do with "Double NAT". Simply make sure the outer router is forwarding port 80 to the inside routers IP and that the inside router is forwarding port 80 to the IP of the server.

As for DMZ, it should not really make a difference, most routers simply treat DMZ as "everything else", so if you have a specific rule in place for HTTP / Port 80 traffic, it should overwrite the DMZ rules.

As for security best practices, if the machine does not do anything else and you want to isolate it, stick it in the DMZ.

Comment: +1 - Removed my much less thorough response.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to enable port forwarding on D-Link router. However you will have to also make sure to change the D-Link's default web service is changed from port 80 to something else. say 8080. So that D-Link's port 80 wont interfear in port forwarding rule. You will have to allow tcp & udp both protocols.

Here is a link that will be helpful in finding your D-Link router and howto port forward on it.

http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/routerindex.htm